# How to make a date delimiter in DatePickerDialog in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, dialog

I have an EditText that a DatePickerDialog is bound to. I am trying to make it so that the DatePickerDialog has a date constraint no older than today and year. I found several examples of how to do this in Java and tried different ways of writing, but nothing worked: either the application crashed, or it did not work correctly. Could you please help me with setting the date constraint for DatePickerDialog?

NewItemActivity.kt

```
class NewItemActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_item)

        val editDate = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editDate)
        editDate.setOnClickListener {
            showDateDialog(editDate)
        }

    }

    private fun showDateDialog(editDate: EditText?) {
        val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val dateSetListener =
            OnDateSetListener { _, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                calendar[Calendar.YEAR] = year
                calendar[Calendar.MONTH] = month
                calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH] = dayOfMonth
                val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
                editDate?.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.time))
            }

        DatePickerDialog(
            this@NewItemActivity,
            dateSetListener,
            calendar[Calendar.YEAR],
            calendar[Calendar.MONTH],
            calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH]).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this for past dates

`datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(cal.getTimeInMillis())`

and for future dates
`datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis())`

```
 fun openDatePickerDialog() {
        // Get Current Date
        val cal: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(this@EditPostActivity,
            { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                val selectedDate: String =
                    dayOfMonth.toString() + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year
                binding.etDate.setText(selectedDate)
            }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        )
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(cal.getTimeInMillis())
        datePickerDialog.show()
    }
```

you can change your date formate with this:

```
 fun convertDateToFormat(
        date: String?,
        format_date: String?,
        format_return: String?
    ): String? {

        var dt = Date()
        try {
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(format_date, Locale.ENGLISH)
            dt = sdf.parse(date)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return DateFormat.format(format_return, dt).toString()
    }




Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        selectedDateStr = sdf.format(today.getTime());
        String currentDate = Global.Companion.convertDateToFormat(selectedDateStr, "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MM-yyyy");
        editText.setText(currentDate);
```

Comment: editDate?.setText(selectedDate) this is for set your date in editText

Comment: oh, i understood. everything is working. thanks! But please answer this question, I need to delete all my previous code and leave only the new function `openDatePickerDialog` ?

Comment: It's just that my date should be formatted in a date field in the usual DD.mm.yyyy format, or write Today if it's today. Could you tell me how to do this in your function?